# Accessing request obejct in zend (1.12) custom validator is legal?

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

I am using `zend framework 1.12`. I have a service for validating token. Service having two functions

1. `setToken`: is responsible for generating token and store in session.
2. `validateToken`: is responsible for regenerating token and validate it with the token stored in session.

Current situation is I am calling `setToken()` function while loading the form and `validateToken()` function will get called after form submission.

Now I want to write `zend custom validator`. Which will do all this process.

Here is my custom validator:

```
class My_Validator_Csrf extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const INVALID_TOKEN = 'invalid_token';

    /**
     * Message templates
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID_TOKEN => "csrf_form_error", 
    );

    /**
     * Generates and set token in session.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();

        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            $csrfValidator = new Website_Service_CsrfValidator();
            $csrfValidator->setToken();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validates csrf token.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isValid($value) 
    {
        $csrfValidator = new Website_Service_CsrfValidator();

        if (!$csrfValidator->validateToken()) {
            $this->_error(self::INVALID_TOKEN);
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Question**:
`setToken()` function must get called while loading the form only and not after form submission. Therefore I am checking if method is not post and for that I am using front controller to having request object there in form validator.

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();

if (!$request->isPost()) {
    $csrfValidator = new Website_Service_CsrfValidator();
    $csrfValidator->setToken();
}
```

I am not sure if this is legal or not. If not please suggest me another way by which I can achieve above scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (note: change 'send' to your submit button's id attribute value):

```
if ($request->getParam('send', false)) { // user submitted form
  ...
} else { // form not yet submitted
  ...
}
```

An alternative option would be to post the form submission to a different url / action.